# Remove a crash from dashboard - Crashlytics

Tags: android, crashlytics

Recently, I decided to migrate from Parse and use the lighter and easier tool, Crashlytics. I've been playing with the interface for a long time and it is already responding every developer needs except one thing:
In addition to close an issue, Is it possible to permanently remove a crash from the crash list in dashboard?

In my case, I planted some force crashes (by throwing a simple `RuntimeException`) in order to test the performance and stability of Crashlytics, but now seeing them beside real crashes is completely on my nerve. Any idea on how to get rid of them?

Answer (score 2):

You can't completely remove the crashes.  You can, however, only show crashes that are open instead of showing all crashes as it sounds like you might be doing.  You could also increment your app version, but that may not be of that much use to just hide crashes that you forced for testing.

Comment: Thanks for your response David, but I already know all the available options for filtering the list in the dashboard, what I really want is just to remove them. You know, it is just some extra obsession!

Answer (score 1):

You can close the issue, so it will not be shown again for the reported version.

Comment: Thank you Rafael, but I already pointed that out in my question.